# Python Pathlib IndexError

Tags: python, directory, lib, pathlib

I'm having trouble with using following lines on my AWS instance. Code works perfectly fine on my Macbook. What's the problem here?
I've checked directory, it exists, there is not problem with path.

[Image - code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knOJ1.png)

```
s = str(Path(Path('__file__').parents[1] / 'lib'))
print(s)
```

.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 594, in __getitem__
raise IndexError(idx)
IndexError: 1
```

Comment: Paste the error as text instead of image. It will be easy to people coming to answer.

Comment: Where is the file that you are running this code from? What is the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you are trying to print the directory named `lib` which is a sibling to the `parent[1]` directory.

But your `Path('__file__')` does not return the current file path.

If you are looking to do this `cd ../lib` from your file directory, you should get the absolute path of the file first and go from there like below.

**samp.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
s = str(Path(Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).parents[1] / 'lib'))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
..../Downloads/f1/samp.py
..../Downloads/lib
```